# using switch case statement for spinner to display images in android programming

Tags: android, switch-statement, spinner, case

I have a spinner which has a list of attractions. I want to use switch case statements to change the image displayed depending on which attraction the user selects.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.attractions_layout);

    ArrayAdapter<String> attractionsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (Attractions.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, attractionEntries);

    attractionsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.spinnerAttractions);
    attractionsSpinner.setAdapter(attractionsAdapter);
    attractionsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int pos = attractionsSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewAttraction);
        String[] information = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.attractions_information_collection);

        switch (position)
        {
        case 0:
            image = R.drawable.avenue_of_stars;
            imageView.setImageResource(image);

            break;
        case 1:
            image = R.drawable.disneyland_fountain;
            imageView.setImageResource(image);

            break;  
        }
    }
```

i get an error message saying that "image cannot be resolved as a variable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a type declared for `image`. Before you start the switch declare it

```
int image = 0;
switch (position)
    {
    case 0:
        image = R.drawable.avenue_of_stars;
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.avenue_of_stars;);

        break;
    case 1:
        image = R.drawable.disneyland_fountain;
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.disneyland_fountain);

        break;  
    }
}
```

Or just use the value for `setImageResource()`

```
  switch (position)
    {
    case 0:
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.avenue_of_stars;);

        break;
    case 1:
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.disneyland_fountain);

        break;  
    }
}
```

Or simplify it with

```
int image = 0;
  switch (position)
    {
    case 0:
        image = R.drawable.avenue_of_stars;
        break;
    case 1:
        image = R.drawable.disneyland_fountain;
        break;  
    }
 imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.disneyland_fountain);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that you have not declared a variable called "image" and thus it doesn't know what you are trying to do when you use that word.

Change your code to be like this:

```
private int image = -1; // <-- you have to declare a variable to be able to use it (in java).
private imageView; // <-- declare this ImageView up here too, while your at it.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.attractions_layout);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewAttraction); //Move findViewById() to here, calling it more than once is wasteful.
    ArrayAdapter<String> attractionsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (Attractions.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, attractionEntries);

    attractionsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.spinnerAttractions);
    attractionsSpinner.setAdapter(attractionsAdapter);
    attractionsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int pos = attractionsSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        String[] information = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.attractions_information_collection);
        switch (position)
        {
        case 0:
            image = R.drawable.avenue_of_stars;
            imageView.setImageResource(image);

            break;
        case 1:
            image = R.drawable.disneyland_fountain;
            imageView.setImageResource(image);

            break;  
        }
    }
```

You must declare an int called `image` in order to be able to store an id into it.

Also note that calling `findViewById()` to get a reference to your image view every time the user selects something is wasteful, you should be getting your reference inside of `onCreate()` and then just using that reference for each subsequent call to `setImageResource()`

One last tip: It seems like you are lacking a grasp on some of the basics of Java programming and syntax. I strongly suggest you take some time now to go back and do some work familiarizing yourself with the java language a bit better before you dive into a complex Android project. Doing so will make your life much easier =).